# Negative Ratio - Is it possible

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I came across this problem recently where

$$A:B = C:A$$
and $B= -9$ and $C = -4$

What is $A$ then?

I got $A^2 = 36$  $\Rightarrow$ $A= \pm 6$

However, as far as my knowledge goes a ratio is always positive

Therefore, we could easily eliminate $A=+6$
and the answer remains $A=-6$

Is my explanation correct, if not then why so? 
Can -ve Ratios exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both $+6$ and $-6$ are correct answers. There is no rule that the ratio has to be positive.

Answer (score 2):

Your work is correct, but it's possible to have a negative ratio. Therefore, both $A=6$ and $A=-6$ will satisfy the ratio.

It is true that a ratio between *natural* numbers will always be positive. That's because the natural numbers are the numbers $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. Since every natural number is positive, every ratio of natural numbers will be as well.

Since you're working with numbers like $-9$ and $-4$, however, it's clear that you're working with the set of *integers*, which are the numbers $\{ \ldots, -3, -2, -1, 0 , 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$. Since some of the integers are negative and some are positive, we can definitely have a negative ratio between them.